# Java hprof question

Tags: java, jvm, profiling

What is the difference between using -agentlib:hprof=cpu=times vs -agentlib:hprof=cpu=sample when running a java class?  I know that cpu=sample causes the jvm to sample the call stack at regular intervals, but what does cpu=times do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hprof=cpu=times` causes the profiler to count the number of times each method was called and measure the time spent in each method.

Read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html) (using browser's find function: cpu=times).